# what is the best way to zip multiple lists in ImmutableJS

Tags: immutable.js

Assume i have a List of Lists. e.g:

```
const l : List<List<number>> = fromJS([[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]])
```

what is the best way (without using toJS()) to zip "l" so i'll get:

```
[[0,4,8],[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7,11]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use [List#zip](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/zip).

```js
const l = Immutable.fromJS([
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10, 11]
]);
const zipped = l.get(0).zip(...l.rest());
console.log(zipped);
// [ [0,4,8], [1,5,9], [2,6,10], [3,7,11] ];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

Note that this returns a list of Arrays. It's easy enough to turn them into Lists though:

```
const zippedLists = zipped.map(List);
```

You might also be interested in [List#zipAll](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/zipAll) if you're zipping lists of different sizes.

Comment: l.rest() will return a List and i don't think "..." works with non array types

Comment: I went into a repl and tried out this exact code. I believe `...` works with any Iterable.